# Design tips: Visual distinction

Tags: html, css, graphics

Currently I have a site where it has a header that looks something like this:
note: dd = dropdown

```
------------------------------------------------------
|[game specific dd][game specific dd]       [main dd]|
------------------------------------------------------
```

now my question is, what sort of visual distinction would you do to define the main dd as the main menu?

here is the site:
webspirited.com/ha2/

Comment: Pure design questions are better asked on http://doctype.com/

Comment: This should indeed Doctype. Additionally, you should explain what you mean with dd before using it. (I highly doubt you mean the html dd-tag and I don't know what else it could be)

Comment: Apologies, Will close this question after JamesStuddart replies again.

Comment: Use the home **icon** instead of the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try sinking the game drop section and giving it a different background colour, this would define it away from the currently active section.

I could whip up an example if you like?

Comment: please do. That would be appreciated.

Comment: send me an email via my website and ill drop you the design proposal www.jamesstuddart.co.uk